# JsQRScanner in Angular5 Not Working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

JsQRScanner in Angular5 Not Working.
I'm not sure I do right?

https://github.com/jbialobr/JsQRScanner

or Who knows how to do it?

in angular-cli.json

.js

```
 "scripts": [
    "jsqrscanner.nocache.js"
  ],
```

.css

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "assets/css/JsQRScanner.css"
  ],
```

in scanner.component.ts

```
declare var JsQRScanner:any;
```

all scanner.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

declare var JsQRScanner:any;

@Component({
 selector: 'app-scanner',
 templateUrl: './scanner.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./scanner.component.css']
 })
 export class ScannerComponent implements OnInit {

 @ViewChild('scanner')scanner:ElementRef;
 @ViewChild('scannedTextMemo')scannedTextMemo:ElementRef;
 @ViewChild('scannedTextMemoHist')scannedTextMemoHist:ElementRef;

 scannerView=this.scanner.nativeElement;
 scannedTextMemoView=this.scannedTextMemo.nativeElement;
 scannedTextMemoHistView=this.scannedTextMemoHist.nativeElement;

 constructor() { 
 //this. JsQRScannerReady();
 }

 onQRCodeScanned(scannedText)
 {
 var scannedTextMemo = this.scannedTextMemoView//////////
  if(scannedTextMemo)
  {
   scannedTextMemo.innerHTML = scannedText;
  }
 var scannedTextMemoHist =this.scannedTextMemoHistView; /////////////
 if(scannedTextMemoHist)
 {
  scannedTextMemoHist.value = scannedTextMemoHist.value + '\n' + scannedText;
 }
 }

 ngOnInit() {

 }

 ngAfterViewInit() {
   var jbScanner = new JsQRScanner(this.onQRCodeScanned);

   jbScanner.setSnapImageMaxSize(300);
   var scannerParentElement =this.scannerView; /////////////////////

   if(scannerParentElement)
   {

     jbScanner.appendTo(scannerParentElement);
   }    
 } 

}
```

Comment: can you share the specific error you getting while running your App.